# Update inventory when sale is made vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a SalesForm whereby a user can add their sales. In my `inventory` table I have total tires, quantity in stock, and quantity sold. I know I have duplicate fields (total tires and quantity in stock), but only the quantity in stock will be used for updating and total tires will be used for referring to check how much they have sold out and which ones are being sold out fast.

What I am trying to do is after I click on save on SalesForm to add new sales, the inventory table should also be updated. The quantity in stock and quantity sold should add how much sold from the sales form and get saved to inventory.

But the calculation isn't working. I see the same information after the update.

This is the code for update:

```
 Public Sub updatestock()
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=golden_star"
    Dim a As Integer
    '  Dim total, onstock, quantity As String
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        '  Dim Sda As MySqlDataAdapter
        a = Val(txtStock.Text) - Val(ComboBox3.Text)
        'total = txtStock.Text
        'quantity = ComboBox3.Text
        'onstock = total - quantity
        Query = "update inventory set quantity_onstock = '" & a & "' where brand = '" & ComboName.Text & "' and size = '" & ComboSize.Text & "' "
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        MessageBox.Show("Stock Updated Successfully")
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader


    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Screenshot frontend:

[image: form]

Screenshot database as it saves the same number it doesn't do the calculation:

[image: database]

Then I pasted the method name `updatestock()` on button click after clicking on save, but it's not working. Can anybody correct me with the update statement?

Comment: Holy SQL Injection vulnerability, Batman!

Comment: Also: those images don't work, and do you ever see the messagebox?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes I do see the message box for stock updated successfully as well as sales added successfully but it's not updating just adding the same number onto the field not subtracting

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn should I be adding the calculation part in the update statement?

Comment: That depends on how the form works and what values are, but probably you need something like  `quantity_onstock = quantity_onstock - @Qty`

Comment: You are using a lot of stored values where you should be calculating them instead. Something like TireInventory that you add a row to when you want to increase your inventory from ordering and then add another row each time you sell tires out of your inventory. Your method leaves you open to instances of invalid state if something is miscalculated and you would have no real way to rectify it. You're better off storing the individual increases in inventory and sales as  transactions in one or more tables and then aggregate the data as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **MUCH** better way to structure the query code:

```
Public Sub UpdateStock(newQty As Integer, brand As String, size As String)
    Dim SQL As String = "UPDATE Inventory SET quantity_onstock = @Qty WHERE brand = @Brand AND size = @Size;"

    Using cn  As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=****;database=golden_star"), _
          cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", newQty)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", brand)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", size)

        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Note the `Using` block, the query parameters, the function arguments instead of form controls, and the lack of error handling or messaging. The method is concerned with running the query and ONLY running the query. You should adopt these changes for **ALL** your queries. Also note the use of `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `ExecuteReader()`.

What this means is you also need to change the code that calls the function. It will need to handle the messages and errors, and provide the parameter arguments.

Whether this fixes your issue is hard to say.

As a further step from here, you can then start moving these SQL methods into their own module, away from any forms code, to create meaningful separation of concerns.